# How to use the git repository after checking out in jenkins pipeline stage

Tags: python, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pull a second github repository in a stage in my jenkins piepline. I want to use the pulled repo to run a test case called test.py in the next stage. 
When running the 'Test' stage I get the error messages as file not found.

```
stage('Checking out first') {
          steps {
            dir('sources') {
                git(url: 'https://github.com/second-repo.git', branch: 'master')
            }
          }
        }

stage('Test') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'qnib/pytest'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'py.test --junit-xml test-reports/results.xml sources/test.py'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'test-reports/results.xml'
                }
            }
        }
```

```
Error: 
+ py.test --junit-xml test-reports/results.xml sources/test.py

============================= test session starts ==============================

platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.5.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0

rootdir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/second-repo, inifile:

plugins: cov-2.5.1



 generated xml file: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/second-repo/test-reports/results.xml 

========================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds =========================

ERROR: file not found: sources/test.py



script returned exit code 4
```

Comment: It's only natural that when you pull sources outside of docker, and then run tests inside docker, that the sources you have pulled will not be seen inside docker.

Comment: So, how should I proceed in this scenario?

Comment: You need to get to a stage where you can run your tests manually first, and then automate it with Jenkins.